# I have an issue on iOS, Android devices when loginPopup() microsoft

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-functions

In Chrome, when the account selection window appears but the requested page is not found.

I am using `@azure/msal-browser": "^3.1.0` and `@azure/msal-react": "^2.0.3"`

```
auth: {
  clientId: CLIENT_ID_MS,
  redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
  authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_MS}`,
},
cache: {
  cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
  temporaryCacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
  storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  secureCookies: false,
  claimsBasedCachingEnabled: true,
},
```